# writing the output from split command to a separate directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ubuntu-14.04

So I'm using split command to split a file into separate lines and save them into a different directory than the current directory which I'm executing the command.

```
split -l 1 -d -a 5 --additional-suffix=.txt file1.dat file toindex/
```

so i want the output files to be written inside `toindex/`, but this gives me a error saying:
 `split: extra operand ‘toindex/’`. 
This works fine if I don't have the output dir path or don't have the prefix ("file").

How do I get this to work? I need to have the prefix as well as the additional-suffix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
split -l 1 -d -a 5 --additional-suffix=.txt file1.dat toindex/file
```

Note that the directory `toindex` must exist.

Comment: FWIW you can make any command output to another directory by piping to a command sequence that has a "cd" in it, for example

    (cd toindex && split ...) <yourfile.dat