# writing the output from split command to a separate directory (redux)

Tags: unix, split

(I know of the preceding question of the same title but the answer there does not work for me)

This command works for me:

```
csplit really_big_file.txt /^H\|756\|/ {*}
```

but I want the output to be in `./split/`:

I tried (as advised in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34391181/189035) answer):

```
csplit really_big_file.txt /^H\|756\|/ {*} ./split/file
csplit really_big_file.txt /^H\|756\|/ {*} /split/file
csplit really_big_file.txt /^H\|756\|/ {*} split/file
```

and I get (variants of):

```
csplit: ‘split/’: invalid pattern
csplit: ‘./split/file’: invalid pattern
```

....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need:

```
mkdir split && csplit really_big_file.txt -f split/file /^H\|756\|/ {*}
```

Example:

```
$ cat inputfile.txt
abc
searchstring
def
searchstring
egh
searchstring
$ mkdir split && csplit inputfile.txt -f split/file /searchstring/ {*}
4
17
17
13
$ ls -Al split/
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users  4 Sep 21 17:12 file00
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 17 Sep 21 17:12 file01
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 17 Sep 21 17:12 file02
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 13 Sep 21 17:12 file03
```